# Using matplotlib, is it possible to set properties for all subplots on a figure at once?

Tags: python, graph, numpy, matplotlib

Using matplotlib (with Python), is it possible to set properties for all subplots on a figure at once?

I've created a figure with multiple subplots, and I currently have something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

listItems1 = np.arange(0, 100)
listItems8 = np.arange(0, 100)
listItems11 = np.arange(0, 100)
figure1 = plt.figure(1)

# First graph on Figure 1
graphA = figure1.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
graphA.plot(listItems1, listItems8, label='Legend Title')
graphA.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='10')
graphA.grid(True)
plt.xticks(range(0, len(listItems1) + 1, 36000), rotation='20', fontsize='7', color='white', ha='right')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Title Text')

# Second Graph on Figure 1
graphB = figure1.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
graphB.plot(listItems1, listItems11, label='Legend Title')
graphB.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='10')
graphB.grid(True)
plt.xticks(range(0, len(listItems1) + 1, 36000), rotation='20', fontsize='7', color='white', ha='right')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Title Text 2')

plt.show()
```

Question, is there a way to set any or all of those properties at once? I'm going to have 6 different subplots on one figure, and it's a bit tedious to keep copy/pasting the same "xticks" settings and "legend" settings over and over again.

Is there some kind of "figure1.legend(..." kind of thing?

Thanks. First post for me. Hello world! ;)

Comment: Yes there is a `figure1.legend`.  Try `help(figure1.legend)` for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a `for` loop:

```
for grph in [graphA, graphB]:
    grph.#edit features here
```

You can also structure the `for` loop differently depending on how you want to do this, e.g.

```
graphAry = [graphA, graphB]
for ind in range(len(graphAry)):
    grph = graphAry[ind]
    grph.plot(listItems1, someList[ind])
#etc
```

The nice thing about subplots is that you can use a `for` loop to plot them too!

```
for ind in range(6):
    ax = subplot(6,1,ind)
    #do all your plotting code once!
```

You'll have to think about how to organize the data you want to plot to make use of the indexing. Make sense?

Whenever I do multiple subplots I think about how to use a `for` loop for them.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That helps a lot! One more thing: "xticks" doesn't seem to accept a named graph as the prefix. I can't tell it which graph to edit, it just edits the graph that's above it. Is there a way to specify which graph "xticks" is editing? Because right now it gives an error if I try to put it in the for loop (AttributeError).

Comment: Hm this is why I tend to write the whole plotting procedure inside a single `for` loop, so that you're making a new subplot and immediately changing its settings. But if this is impractical (e.g. you're working in the interpreter window) you can call your desired subplot into focus by just doing subplot(xxx), whichever one you want to edit. Then xticks should edit that one. That's my best guess.

Comment: @rockyourteeth try grph.set_xticks.

Comment: @esmit, hey thanks! That's definitely what I needed in the first place. It looks like using that together with grph.set_xticklabels accomplishes what I needed.

Answer (score 7):

If your subplots are actually sharing an axis/some axes, you may be interested in specifying the `sharex=True` and/or `sharey=True` kwargs to `subplots`.

See John Hunter explaining more in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNRJwENqEUY&t=4m20s).  It can give your graph a much cleaner look and reduce code repetition.

Comment: Cheers.  I often go back to it myself; turns out the creator of the library knows a thing or two about how to use it.  :)